# Extruded symbols going round corners

Tags: extrude

Bit of and odd issue but i'm trying to model the attached image.

I can make the shape and I can model the symbols but i have no idea hows to make the symbols conform to the shape.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you having trouble with topo-- joining the pen to the symbols-- or is that of no concern?  Are you just looking for techniques to bend a symbol?  If so, it would be useful to see what kinds of mesh (wireframes) your using for your symbols.

Comment: This might be easier if you create the basic shape, create a UV map and use an image with the symbols to displace the geometry.